# Change order status after invoice in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2

How do I change the order status **NOT STATE** after I create an invoice in Magento 2?

I created a custom status called `Invoiced`, assigned it to state processing.

> Status code: processing[Invoiced]

When I submit an invoice I want the order to be assigned to this new status.

What additional steps do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

In your

> Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_invoice_pay">
        <observer name="invoice_pay_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\InvoicePayAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Observer\InvoicePayAfter.php

```
class InvoicePayAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       \\You Can get Your Order Here Now Change its Status using
```

//it is not this to use here for inoivce
//$observer->getOrder();
$order = $observer->getInvoice()->getOrder();
\Or Something Like that
}
}

Answer (score 0):

use evnt **sales_order_invoice_pay** which is fired in both frontend and beckend.

Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_invoice_pay">
        <observer name="invoice_pay_after" instance="Vrinsoft\ShippingNoteToSupplier\Observer\InvoicePayAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Observer\InvoicePayAfter.php

```
<?php


 namespace Vrinsoft\ShippingNoteToSupplier\Observer;

 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class InvoicePayAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface

{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
        //echo json_encode($order->getData());exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First need to create a an event.xml file in your modules etc directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_invoice_pay">
   <observer name="fs_invoice_pay_after" instance="Custom\StatusChange\Observer\InvoicePayAfter" />
</event>
</config>
```

Then you need to create an InvoicePayAfter.php file inside Observer directory like below.

```
<?php
namespace Custom\StatusChange\Observer;
class InvoicePayAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {
   
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

      $order = $observer->getInvoice()->getOrder();

      if ($order instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) {
            if($order->getState() == 'processing') {
                $order->setStatus('processing');
                $order->save();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

That's all hope this will help somebody.